# Emacs doesn't fill window

Tags: emacs

I'm using GNOME and xmonad.  When I first open Emacs, it doesn't use the full width and height of its window.  If I then change the size of the window, emacs corrects itself to fill the window, and works perfectly thereafter.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

From `man emacs`:

starting emacs with `emacs -fs` opens emacs in full screen mode

to automate this, add the following to your `.bashrc` file (found in `/home/user/.bashrc`):

```
alias emacs='emacs -fs'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's fixable; this is a longstanding Emacs bug/annoyance.

Comment: Has anyone reported it?

Comment: Do you have a link to the bug?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me if placed in the last line of my .emacs:

`(if (window-system) (set-frame-size (selected-frame) 1280 1000))`